# Conditionally include a line based on an option with pgfpackages

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, package-writing, ifthenelse

I am trying to design a small package, mostly for test purpose. Currently the package looks like this:

```
% eqbox.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{eqbox}[2019/01/01 Boxed Equations]

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{fancybox}
\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\pgfkeys{
    /eqbox/.cd,
    colframe/.store in = \colframe,
    colframe = black,
    colback/.store in = \colback,
    colback = white,
    shadow/.store in = \shadow,
    shadow = undefined,
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/eqbox}

\tcbset{
    highlight math style={
        enhanced,
        sharp corners,
        breakable,
        colframe=\colframe,
        colback=\colback,
\ifx\undefined\shadow
\else
        shadow={2pt}{-2pt}{0mm}{\shadow},
\fi
        boxrule=0.4pt,
        boxsep = 3pt,
        left = 0pt,
        right = 0pt,
        top = 0pt,
        bottom = 0pt
    }
}
```

and I can try to use it this way:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, onecolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eqbox}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath{x^2 + 3}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

However it does not work. My intent is that:

- By default, `\usepackage{eqbox}` does not provide any shadow
- If the user writes `\usepackage[shadow=blue]{eqbox}` then equations are put in boxes with a blue shadow

How to make that work? (I think I do not know how to use `\ifx` to make that work)

EDIT: I also tried:

```
\ifdefined\shadow
        shadow={2pt}{-2pt}{0mm}{\shadow},
\fi
```

but it does not work either

Comment: One quick remark: you have `shadow = undefined,` but a backslash in `\ifx\undefined\shadow`. (I am not saying that adding the backslash will fix it.)

Comment: You can add `\ifx\shadow\empty\else\tcbset{shadow={2pt}{-2pt}{0mm}{\shadow}}\fi` outside of `\tcbset`. And then simply set `shadow=` (to set the `\shadow` to empty) or `shadow=red` to set it to red. But I do not understand why you need the `\shadow` macro to do all this.  You can simply set `/eqbox/shadow/.style = {shadow={2pt}{-2pt}{0mm}{#1}}`.

Comment: @Kpym: would there be any trick to put the ifx/else inside the tcbset. In this specific case your trick works, but I'm sure I will encounter cases where I would like to have if/else conditions inside some command.

Comment: I can't see why you need to put conditionals directly inside `\pgfset`, `\tcbset`, `\tikzset`. The conditionals should be in the `.code` part of the keys in general or outside this "key" environments.